# Laravel 5.6 eager load nested childrelations

Tags: laravel, loading, laravel-5.6, eager

I'm having an issue with getting child relations from a Card object to a User object. The relations are as following:

```
'User' -> hasOne 'Company' 
'Company' -> hasMany 'Card'
```

So the other way around is:

```
'Card' -> belongsTo 'Company' 
'Company' -> belongsTo 'User'
```

My Card model has got this:

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

My Company model has got this:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function cards()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Card');
}
```

My User model has got this:

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Company');
}
```

**What I want to do is: in the User model I want to eager load all cards from that user.** So my code looks like this:

```php
$cards = Card::with('company.user')->get();
```

But it's constantly returning me all the card records in the database, not the ones that are from the logged in user itself. There definitely
is a userID, cause when I dump $this->id in the User model, I'm getting the ID '1'. In the database I've configured all foreign keys so that won't be the problem I assume.

Table 'cards' has a foreign key to 'company_id', and table 'companies' has a foreign key to 'user_id', they are all set by the migration script, which looks like this:

```php
Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->unsignedInteger('company_id');
        $table->timestamp('expires_at')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_debit_allowed')->default(1);
        $table->string('cancelled_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('cancelled_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
    });
```

What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: How would `Card::with('company.user')->get()` know about the logged in user? Don't you mean something like `Auth::user()->load('company.cards')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `User` model, you can add it to the `$with` array:

```
// this will eager load the company and cards for every user query, so beware!
protected $with = ['company.cards'];
```

Or create a new function `cards`:

```
public function cards()
{
    return $this->company->cards;
}

$cards = $user->cards();

// use the auth helper to get logged in user's cards
$cards = auth()->user()->cards();
```

This should work for accessing via `Card`:

```
$cards = Card::whereHas('company.user', function ($query) {
    $query->whereKey(auth()->id());
})->get();
```

Comment: That's where you'd use the `$with` array.

Comment: Updated with another approach.

Comment: That last thing with the whereHas and whereKey works! Thanks